# Polygon not show in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I obtain the polygon coordinates through an AJAX request and I pass all the coordinates to an associative array.

The problem is, when I create the Polygon this don't show, but if I create it with the coordinates example this show.

This is the code:

```
var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.7281512, lng: -58.262616},
            zoom: 10
        });

        var coords = new Array();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=R&osm_id=2532299&polygon_geojson=1',
            data: { get_param: 'value' },
            success: function (data) {

                $.each(data.geojson.coordinates[0], function( index, value ) {

                    if(typeof value[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof value[1] !== 'undefined') {
                        coords.push({lat: value[0], lng: value[1]});
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: coords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        zone.setMap(map);
    }
```

If I make the same, with the google example, this works fine. I don't know why my associative array don't work.

Code of the example:

```
var map;
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: {lat: -34.7281512, lng: -58.262616},
            zoom: 10
        });

        var triangleCoords = [
            {lat: -34.817177, lng: -58.500948},
            {lat: -34.688414, lng: -58.500948},
            {lat: -34.688414, lng: -58.336764},
            {lat: -34.817177, lng: -58.336764},
            {lat: -34.817177, lng: -58.500948}
        ];

        var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths: triangleCoords,
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35
        });

        zone.setMap(map);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues with the posted code.

1. Your `$.ajax` call is asynchronous, so the data isn't available when you try to populate the `paths` attribute of the polygon.  You need to use the data in the callback function when/where it is available.
2. You have the latitude and longitude reversed in the path of the polygon.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=R&osm_id=2532299&polygon_geojson=1',
  data: {
    get_param: 'value'
  },
  success: function(data) {
    var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map
    });
    $.each(data.geojson.coordinates[0], function(index, value) {
      if (typeof value[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof value[1] !== 'undefined') {
        coords.push({
          lat: value[1],
          lng: value[0]
        });
      }
      zone.setPath(coords);
    });
  }
})
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/unn2x09t/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {
      lat: -34.7281512,
      lng: -58.262616
    },
    zoom: 10
  });

  var coords = new Array();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&osm_type=R&osm_id=2532299&polygon_geojson=1',
    data: {
      get_param: 'value'
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
      });
      $.each(data.geojson.coordinates[0], function(index, value) {
        if (typeof value[0] !== 'undefined' && typeof value[1] !== 'undefined') {
          coords.push({
            lat: value[1],
            lng: value[0]
          });
        }
        zone.setPath(coords);
      });
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why value[1] is taken as latitude and not value[0] ?

Comment: That is the way GeoJSON is defined.